# Using styled-components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Can someone tell me why my styled components aren't working. I was following an example where the person put the css right in their react app using back ticks but my is not working like thiers.

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Wrapper = styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    left: ${(props) => (props.position === "left" ? "20px" : "380px")}
    top: 20px
    background: ${(props) => (props.lampOn ? "orange" : "lightgrey")};
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
`;

const Lamp = ({ lampOn, position }) => {
  return (
    <Wrapper lampOn={lampOn} position={position}>
      <div>Test light oo </div>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
export default Lamp;
```

Comment: did you try like that ? < Wrapper/>

Comment: You need to use it in your App like above.

Comment: I just added more code that I have. I had <Wrapper> used

Comment: Missing some semi colons, e.g., `top: 20px;`. I would recommend you try to try it out incrementally. E.g., set the `width` and `height` and `background` first, make sure them work and then add other CSS attributes.

Comment: You can also check the browser console log, see if there is any errors.

Answer (score 3):

Missing semi colons:

Refer to https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-thagj7

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <Lamp lampOn position="left" />
    </div>
  );
}

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  left: ${props => (props.position === 'left' ? '20px' : '380px')};
  top: 200px;
  background: ${props => (props.lampOn ? 'orange' : 'lightgrey')};
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
`;

const Lamp = ({ lampOn, position }) => {
  return (
    <Wrapper lampOn={lampOn} position={position}>
      <div>Test light oo </div>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```